# Error when assigning an enum to a variable

Tags: c++, enums

I was creating a code to show the months of the year according to user input, but I get an error at the line **"mes = n"** . Here's the code below:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
int n = 0;
enum meses {Janeiro = 1, Fevereiro = 2, Marco = 3, Abril = 4, Maio = 5, Junho= 6,   
Julho = 7, Agosto = 8, Setembro = 9, Outubro = 10,Novembro = 11, Dezembro = 12}mes;
cin>>n;
mes = n; // That's where I get an error!
switch(mes)
{
    case Janeiro: cout<<"janeiro"; break;
    case Fevereiro: cout<<"fevereiro"; break;
    case Marco: cout<<"marco"; break;
    case Abril: cout<<"abril"; break;
    case Maio: cout<<"maio"; break;
    case Junho: cout<<"junho"; break;
    case Julho: cout<<"julho"; break;
    case Agosto: cout<<"agosto"; break;
    case Setembro: cout<<"setembro"; break;
    case Outubro: cout<<"outubro"; break;
    case Novembro: cout<<"novembro"; break;
    case Dezembro: cout<<"dezembro"; break;
    default: cout<<"invalido"; break;
}
return 0;
}
```

The compiler error is: "invalid conversion from int to main()::meses".

Comment: When posting questions, please add the compiler output so we know the error you are getting

Comment: @QualityCatalyst `mes` is defined in the line starting with `enum meses`.

Comment: @excalibur1491 OK, I did edit now and added the compiler error. I'm new here, so thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In standard C++ there is no implicit conversion *to* `enum` type. So you cannot write simply `mes = n;`. To make this conversion you need to do it explicitly, e.g.:

```
mes = static_cast<meses>(n);
```

However, there *is* implicit conversion from unscoped `enum`s *to* `int`. (Technically this is integer promotion). So you would not need a cast for:

```
int x = Janeiro;
```

So, another solution to your problem would be to use `int` for storing the value that was input. In fact you already have `n` fulfilling that role:

```
switch(n)
{
case Janeiro: .....
```

As above, no cast is required for `case Janeiro` because unscoped enumerators promote to integer type.

Technically you should use `std::underlying_type<meses>::type` instead of `int`, in case there are enumerators larger than `INT_MAX`.

If you want there to be a cast required for both directions of conversion (enum to int, and int to enum) then you must use a *scoped enumeration*, i.e. `enum class meses`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a couple of issues, I give you 3 possible fixed and explain below:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int n = 0;
    //Using a local variable only:
    //*
    enum meses {Janeiro = 1, Fevereiro = 2, Marco = 3, Abril = 4, Maio = 5, Junho= 6,   
    Julho = 7, Agosto = 8, Setembro = 9, Outubro = 10,Novembro = 11, Dezembro = 12}mes;
    cin>>n;
    mes = (meses)n; // Cast to convert int into a meses_type
    //*/

    //Or declaring the enum:
    /*
    enum meses {Janeiro = 1, Fevereiro = 2, Marco = 3, Abril = 4, Maio = 5, Junho= 6,   
    Julho = 7, Agosto = 8, Setembro = 9, Outubro = 10,Novembro = 11, Dezembro = 12};
    cin>>n;
    meses mes = (meses)n; // Cast to convert int into a meses_type
    //*/

    // Using typedef
    /*
    typedef enum meses {Janeiro = 1, Fevereiro = 2, Marco = 3, Abril = 4, Maio = 5, Junho= 6,   
    Julho = 7, Agosto = 8, Setembro = 9, Outubro = 10,Novembro = 11, Dezembro = 12}meses_type;
    cin>>n;
    meses_type mes = (meses_type)n; // Cast to convert int into a meses_type
    //*/

    switch(mes)
    {
        case Janeiro: cout<<"janeiro"; break;
        case Fevereiro: cout<<"fevereiro"; break;
        case Marco: cout<<"marco"; break;
        case Abril: cout<<"abril"; break;
        case Maio: cout<<"maio"; break;
        case Junho: cout<<"junho"; break;
        case Julho: cout<<"julho"; break;
        case Agosto: cout<<"agosto"; break;
        case Setembro: cout<<"setembro"; break;
        case Outubro: cout<<"outubro"; break;
        case Novembro: cout<<"novembro"; break;
        case Dezembro: cout<<"dezembro"; break;
        default: cout<<"invalido"; break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The first solution is what you intended I think.

1) Creates a variable of type `enum meses` called `mes`. The enum type can only be used once here, for that variable.
2) Created the enum, then the variable. this way you can create more than one instance of that enum type.
3) Makes use of a typedef to shorten the name (although not very useful, more interesting for struct's than for enum's).

Finally, to put an int into a variable of a enum type, you need to cast the into into the enum type. C++ thinks of those things as completely different objects (even though the enum is eventually just a bunch of ints).

Comment: as a general principle I'd recommend using C++-style casts, i.e. `mes = static_cast<meses>(n);` , because there is less risk of a mistake.  Your version 3 adds verbiage for no reason

Comment: You are right for the cast. (The third version was just to show the use of typedefs, the syntax used by OP made me think that maybe that was his intention but forgot the typedef keyword)

Answer (score 0):

You've got the syntax wrong. This is how it should be:

```
enum meses {
  Janeiro = 1, Fevereiro = 2, Marco = 3, Abril = 4, Maio = 5, Junho= 6,
  Julho = 7, Agosto = 8, Setembro = 9, Outubro = 10,Novembro = 11, Dezembro = 12
};
cin>>n;
meses mes = n;
switch(mes)
...
```

Or for a scoped enum (c++11):

```
enum class meses {
  Janeiro = 1, Fevereiro = 2, Marco = 3, Abril = 4, Maio = 5, Junho= 6,
  Julho = 7, Agosto = 8, Setembro = 9, Outubro = 10,Novembro = 11, Dezembro = 12
};
...
```

Where you can use `meses::janiero` etc...

Comment: I think OP was trying to create a variable called `mes` of the enum-type. The syntax is not wrong, it's just that the enum won't ever be reusable (but there is nothing wrong with that, if that's what he wants).
And your solution does not compile either (standard c++), because of the "meses mes =n;": `10:13: error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'main()::meses' [-fpermissive]`

Answer (score 0):

You could just use `switch(n)`:

```
int main() {
    int n = 0;
    enum meses {Janeiro = 1, Fevereiro = 2, Marco = 3, Abril = 4, Maio = 5, 
        Junho= 6, Julho = 7, Agosto = 8, Setembro = 9, Outubro = 10, 
        Novembro = 11, Dezembro = 12};

    cin >> n;
    switch(n)
    {
        case Janeiro: cout<<"janeiro"; break;
        case Fevereiro: cout<<"fevereiro"; break;
        case Marco: cout<<"marco"; break;
        case Abril: cout<<"abril"; break;
        case Maio: cout<<"maio"; break;
        case Junho: cout<<"junho"; break;
        case Julho: cout<<"julho"; break;
        case Agosto: cout<<"agosto"; break;
        case Setembro: cout<<"setembro"; break;
        case Outubro: cout<<"outubro"; break;
        case Novembro: cout<<"novembro"; break;
        case Dezembro: cout<<"dezembro"; break;
        default: cout<<"invalido"; break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Or use `static_cast<meses>(n)`:

```
int main() {
    int n = 0;
    enum meses {Janeiro = 1, Fevereiro = 2, Marco = 3, Abril = 4, Maio = 5, 
        Junho= 6, Julho = 7, Agosto = 8, Setembro = 9, Outubro = 10, 
        Novembro = 11, Dezembro = 12}mes;

    cin >> n;
    mes = static_cast<meses>(n);
    switch(mes)
    {
        case Janeiro: cout<<"janeiro"; break;
        case Fevereiro: cout<<"fevereiro"; break;
        case Marco: cout<<"marco"; break;
        case Abril: cout<<"abril"; break;
        case Maio: cout<<"maio"; break;
        case Junho: cout<<"junho"; break;
        case Julho: cout<<"julho"; break;
        case Agosto: cout<<"agosto"; break;
        case Setembro: cout<<"setembro"; break;
        case Outubro: cout<<"outubro"; break;
        case Novembro: cout<<"novembro"; break;
        case Dezembro: cout<<"dezembro"; break;
        default: cout<<"invalido"; break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```